# Rails7 Active Srorage could not update my image.[param is missing or the value is empty: activity]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I try to upload image with active storage and cropper.js. so It works with first upload image doing well. but when I try to not attached any image and submit form, that will get error [param is missing or the value is empty: activity].

is there anyone helping me?

controller

```
  def update_image
    @activity = Activity.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @activity.update(activity_params)
    if @activity.save
      redirect_to management_path(@activity)
    else
      render 'edit_image_modal'
    end
  end

  def activity_params
    params.require(:activity).permit(:image, :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_width, :crop_height, :custom_url)
  end
```

view

```
  <%= simple_form_for @activity, url: {action: 'update_image'}, data: { turbo: false, controller: 'validate', validate_target: 'form' } do |f| %>
    <div data-controller='image-upload image-cropper' data-image-cropper-model-value='activity'
        data-image-upload-token-value="<%= direct_upload_token("Activity#image") %>"
        data-image-upload-attachment-value='Activity#image'>
      <%= f.file_field :image, 'data-image-upload-target': 'input', 'data-action': 'image-upload#changed' %>
      <p>
        <% set_image = @activity.image.attached? ? @activity.image.variant(@activity.crop_constraints) : "https://res.cloudinary.com/hanfn5d8l/image/authenticated/s--lp_ZlvDw--/v1649146879/main/no_image.png" %>
        <%= image_tag set_image, class: 'w-full rounded mb-4', 'data-image-upload-target': 'photo', 'data-image-cropper-target': 'photo',
          'data-action': 'image-uploaded->image-cropper#changed' %>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
      <%= f.button :submit, 'submit', data: { action: 'validate#submitForm'} %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

model

```
class Activity < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image

  def crop_constraints
    return {} unless crop_x && crop_y && crop_width && crop_height
    { crop: [crop_x.to_f, crop_y.to_f, (crop_width + crop_x).to_f, (crop_height + crop_y).to_f] }
  end

  validates :image,
  content_type: %i(gif png jpg jpeg),
  size: { less_than_or_equal_to: 5.megabytes },
  dimension: { width: { max: 3000 }, height: { max: 3000 } }
end
```

Comment: Post your Activity model code

Comment: thanks for comment me Joe and Added my model code.

Comment: In your params, after submitting the form, do you see something like `Parameters: {"image"=>"string"....}` ?

Comment: this is the parms. #<ActionController::Parameters {"_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"NN2pIiQ3xU5vb2XXqKlyqTGC7q3ZuHsQ-gTG4iRW9mOWHiEO0w9z6mNqjj39lcmYjbnojDHtEz3wkqum-HEeiQ", "controller"=>"activities", "action"=>"update_image", "id"=>"0ae062a5d679290be730"} permitted: false>

Comment: Then you're not passing anything from your form to controller. You have to debug it